# Shifting Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a hermitian positive semi-definite matrix and $\mathbf{B}$ be a hermitian positive definite matrix. Then I am interested in the eigenvalues of matrix $\mathbf{C}(t)=\mathbf{A}-t\mathbf{B}$ where $t$ is a real parameter. Note that when $t=0$, $\mathbf{C}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. As $t$ increases, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{C}$ moves towards the left on the real line and crosses the origin. At one point, the last positive eigenvalue of $\mathbf{C}$ will also cross origin at which point, $\mathbf{C}$ will become negative semi-definite. I want the smallest $t$ for which this happens. In other words, I want to solve 
\begin{align}
\max_{t}~t \\
\lambda_{max}(\mathbf{C}(t))\geq 0
\end{align}
where $\lambda_{max}(.)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\det(C(t))$ is a polynomial in $t$, of degree $n$ (where your matrices are $n \times n$).  You want the greatest positive root of this polynomial.

You could also call this the greatest eigenvalue of $B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I got it as largest eigenvalue of $B^{-1}A$. How do I prove this?

Comment: $M_1 M_2$ and $M_2 M_1$ always have the same eigenvalues (the same nonzero eigenvalues, if $M_1$ is $m \times n$ and $M_2$ is $n \times m$), but $B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}$ is Hermitian.

Comment: still no success, how do you prove that it is the largest eigenvalue of $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$

Comment: $\det(A - \lambda B) = \det(B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} - \lambda I) B^{1/2}) = \det(B) \det(B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} - \lambda I)$

Comment: i am sorry if it so simple, but i am not getting it?

Comment: Which part are you not getting?

Comment: $\det(A - \lambda B) = \det(B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} - \lambda I) B^{1/2}) = \det(B) \det(B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} - \lambda I)$ , from this how do I conclude that the largest $\lambda$ should be the largest eigenvalue of $B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}$?

Comment: An eigenvalue of $C(t)$ is $0$ iff $C(t) = A - t B$ is singular iff  $B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} - t I$ is singular
iff $t$ is an eigenvalue of $B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}$. Moreover, by Sylvester's Law of Inertia the numbers of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues of $C(t)$ and 
$B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2} - t I$ are the same.